# Get Accordion Pane active, Ajax, ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm not an expert, I must use an Ajax Accordion Panel in an application and there are several actions according with Accordion Pane is active, my accordion is like:

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="Scriptmng_Rep" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <ajax:Accordion ID="ReposAccordion" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" FadeTransitions="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None"
            >
            <Panes>
                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordPane_RepoFact" runat="server" >
                    <Header><a href="#" class="href">Reporte Facturacion</a></Header>
                    <Content>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Repo_Fact" runat="server">
                            <asp:Table ID="table1"
                                runat="server"
                                Width="550"
                                BackColor="Orange"
                                BorderColor="DarkRed"
                                BorderWidth="2"
                                ForeColor="Snow"
                                CellPadding="5"
                                CellSpacing="5">
                                <asp:TableRow
                                    ID="TableRow4"
                                    runat="server"
                                    BackColor="OrangeRed">
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </Content>
                </ajax:AccordionPane>

                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordPane_RepoEnvNoDev" runat="server" >
                    <Header><a href="#" class="href">Enviados no Devueltos</a></Header>
                    <Content>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Repo_EnvNoDev" runat="server">
                            <asp:Table ID="table2"
                                runat="server"
                                Width="550"
                                BackColor="Orange"
                                BorderColor="DarkRed"
                                BorderWidth="2"
                                ForeColor="Snow"
                                CellPadding="5"
                                CellSpacing="5">
                                <asp:TableRow
                                    ID="TableRow3"
                                    runat="server"
                                    BackColor="OrangeRed">
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </Content>
                </ajax:AccordionPane>

            </Panes>
        </ajax:Accordion>
    </div>
```

There are more panes, My question is how can I get which is the selected pane?
I need it for the actions.

I hope, please you can help me.

best regards

Comment: Using jQuery/JavaScript or ?

Comment: Hi Mark, This accordion don't use jQuery or javascript, Its using an AjaxControlToolkit.dll and works, It's referenced at top of code:       
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reportes.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reportes" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHTitulo" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>                                                                                       etc etc....

Comment: I haven't worked with Accordion. You have header for each of the Accordion pane. I assume it is unique. So, on click of the header you can identify the Accordion pane. Hope, this will help you

Comment: @angel_neo this [AjaxControlToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit)? it has [`SelectedIndex`](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Accordion#selectedindex) property, but i'm not sure, never used the library. also, it would be best if you reduce the clutter in the code, is the background colour important for the problem at hand?